# Req.body returns { NaN: " " } in server console.log when passing object to API POST route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, crud, api-design

I am getting an error when I post to my API Route for creating a document in my collection. the data is user information being posted too a database

Here is the form submit:

```js
handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const userId = localStorage.getItem("userId")
    const newForm = {
      id: userId,
      title: this.state.title,
      main: this.state.main,
      summary: this.state.summary
    };
    console.log(newForm);
    API.addForm(newForm)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
    })
  }
  
  // =============== API =========== //
  
  addForm: function(form) {
        return axios.post("/api/form", + form);
    },
```

The client side console.log prints out the correct object with all the appropriate values in the object but when it hits the back end server the POST Body returns {NaN: ""} throws the error of UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: validation error And the response fails

here is the back end API Route:

```js
// ======== Index.js for API ======= // 

router.use("/api",require("./apiRoutes.js")(passport));

// ============== apiRoutes.js ============= //

router.route("/form")
    .post(formController.addRecipe);
  
 // ============= Controller ============ //
 
 addForm: function(req, res) {
        console.log("addForm Function")
        console.log("======================")
        console.log(req.body)
        db.Form.create(req.body)
        .then(form => {
            console.log(form)
            return db.User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.body.id }, { form: form._id }, { new:true });
        })
        .then(userInfo => {
            res.json(userInfo);
        })
    }
```

Comment: What is `+form` supposed to do?

Comment: its the form param for when I send the newForm object into the addForm route

Comment: And why the `+` ? any specific reason?

Comment: not specifically It was an example I pulled from an old class repository, I can try to remove it and see if that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your addForm function axios.post second parameter is an object and you don’t need + there so Remove +

```
addForm: function(form) {
    return axios.post("/api/form", form);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The + operator coerces the `form` object to a number. As an object cannot be converted into a number in a manner that makes sense it will return `NaN` (not a number). The following should solve it:

```
addForm: function(form) {
    return axios.post("/api/form", form);
 }
```

Here is an example of where the `NaN` comes from:

```js
let obj = {prop1: 1};

let nonSensicalNumber = +obj;

console.log(nonSensicalNumber);
```

Comment: yeah thank you that makes total sense, just started learning development 6 months ago, trying to break the habit of those tiny errors

Comment: Good to hear!! understand that if you put a plus before any expression JS will convert it to a number. Don't forget that javascript has different data types (string, int, boolean), just because you don't have to declare them they are stilll present and can cause bugs if you don't know how they behave